# Error Installing Gulp Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015 for ASP.NET Core 1.0 Application- 
With NPM I was able to successfully install Gulp (3.9.1), gulp-concat(2.6.1), gulp-cssmin(0.1.7), gulp-uglify(2.0.1), rimraf(2.6.1)

```
npm install gulp -g
```

However for Visual Studio 2017 for ASP.NET Core 1.1 Application- 
when installing Gulp via NPM:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

I'm getting Error: "try running command as root/Administrator"
The npm-debug.txt is too large so I took a screenshot:

[image]

I believe I have External Tools Environment set-up correctly with $(PATH) moved to the top:

[image]

The Git Enviroment Variable on my machine is:  C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

In Visual Studio 2017 I only was able to install Gulp (3.9.1) with:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

With just Gulp (3.9.1), I'm unable to create a gulpfile.js which I need to copy package files to www/lib directory

Am I missing something for Visual Studio 2017 in order to install all of the Gulp Components Gulp (3.9.1), gulp-concat(2.6.1), gulp-cssmin(0.1.7), gulp-uglify(2.0.1), rimraf(2.6.1)

with this `npm install gulp -g` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the gulp packages individually:

```
npm install gulp-concat --save-dev
npm install gulp-cssmin --save-dev
npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
npm install gulp-rimraf --save-dev
```

I'm still not clear why this does not work: `npm install gulp -g`

I was able to create `gulfile.js` to move necessary packages ie jQuery out of `node_Modules` to `www/lib`

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't be installing gulp globally, see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md where it states `If you've previously installed gulp globally, run npm rm --global gulp before following these instructions.`.